When I run `pip --version` from the global Python environment, it displays the version of pip installed in my Anaconda environment
I noticed the issue when I wrote pip list in the global Python environment and found all the packages downloaded while I was using Conda with pip install.
So, I tried running pip --version both in the global Python environment and in Conda, and I get the same result, which is pip 23.3.1 from C:\Users\giova\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.11), so I guess they are both using the same pip.
Additionally, when I run where pip, I get the following output: C:\Users\giova\anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe     C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\pip.exe. How can I resolve this discrepancy and ensure that the correct pip version is displayed from the global Python environment and that if I dowload a package within the conda environment it is isolated to that environment?

Can you say what you mean by "global python environment" and "in conda" where are you running these commands from? Have you checked the box about adding conda to PATH when you installed it?

There is no discrepancy, you have the same version of pip in both environments. I have not run Python in Anaconda so I assume that is similar to a virtual environment. So assuming you set everything correctly when you want to switch to the Anaconda environment there should be no problem.

@FlyingTeller With "global Python environment" I mean the Python installation that you access when you run Python commands from the command prompt (CMD) or terminal without activating any specific virtual environment. With "in conda" I mean after conda activate I write in the command prompt something like pip install something. Yes I checked teh box about adding conda to PATH

Guessing you have the anaconda pip on your path earlier than regular pip, more info? PATH might be helpful

Information in this article may be relevant.  If you ever used Ctrl+C in your conda environment in the same session, then apparently you might not actually be in it anymore.

I managed to solve the issue. It turns out Anaconda was appearing before regular Python in the PATH. This could also be inferred from when I typed where pip getting in order first C:\Users\giova\anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe before C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\pip.exe. I solved it by moving C:\Users\giova\anaconda and C:\Users\giova\anaconda\Scripts in the user environment variables path below everything else. Now, when I run where pip, I get C:\Users\giova\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\pip.exe first and then C:\Users\giova\anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe.
